# How to change text of PyQt standardButtons_

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to display a question messageBox with custom text in PyQt so that I get a result similar to:

```
Which option do you choose?

[Option A] [Option B]
```

I tried to achieve this using

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

optionA = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.standardButton(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton())
optionA.setText("Option A")

optionB = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.standardButton(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton())
optionB.setText("Option B")

buttonReply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
buttonReply.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Question)
buttonReply.setWindowTitle('Options')
buttonReply.setText('Which option do you choose?')
buttonReply.setStandardButtons(optionA | optionB)
buttonReply.setDefaultButton(optionA)
buttonReply.exec()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> QPushButton *QMessageBox::addButton(const QString &text, QMessageBox::ButtonRole role)
>
> Creates a button with the given text, adds it to the message box for the specified role, and returns it.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QMessageBox, QPushButton


class MessageBox(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MessageBox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("im.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle("MessageBox")
        self.setFixedSize(400, 300)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        button = QPushButton("MessageBox Question", self)
        button.move(50, 60)
        button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked) 

    def onClicked(self):
        messageBox = QMessageBox(self)
        messageBox.setWindowIcon(QIcon("Ok.png"))
        messageBox.setWindowTitle("Options")
        messageBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question)
        messageBox.setText("Question")
        messageBox.setInformativeText("Which option do you choose?")
        
        buttonoptionA = messageBox.addButton("optionA", QMessageBox.YesRole)    
        buttonoptionB = messageBox.addButton("optionB", QMessageBox.AcceptRole)  
        messageBox.setDefaultButton(buttonoptionA)
        
        messageBox.exec_()

        if messageBox.clickedButton() == buttonoptionA:
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Information", "Click Buiion: optionA")
        elif messageBox.clickedButton() == buttonoptionB:
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Information", "Click Buiion: optionB")
           

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    aplicacion = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventana = MessageBox()
    ventana.show()
    sys.exit(aplicacion.exec_())
```

[image]